# How can I concatenate the string to the number at targetIndex?

Tags: java

1. For the `stringArray` concatenate the string at `targetIndex` in `stringArray` to the number at `targetIndex` in `numberArray`
2. For the `numberArray` make the element at index `targetIndex` equals to the sum of the first and the fourth element

```
String[] courseNames = new String[] { "Programming", "Database", "HCI", "Network", "Security", "Mathematics", "AI" };
int[] studentsInCourse = new int[] { 30, 25, 35, 40, 50, 20, 47 };

//public static void arrayOnIndex(int[] studentsArray, String[] coursesArray, int targetIndex)
```

Comment: Can you provide some required output examples?

Comment: Please post code showing what you have tried already.

Comment: The result Arrays After manipulation:                                           
AI, Database, HCI, Network, Security, Mathematics, Programming                
30, 25, 35, 40, 50, 70, 47 @saintlyzero

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this would do the trick:

```java
public static void arrayOnIndex(int[] studentsArray, String[] coursesArray, int targetIndex) {
        System.out.println(coursesArray[targetIndex] + ' ' + studentsArray[targetIndex]);
        studentsArray[targetIndex] = studentsArray[0] + studentsArray[3];
    }
```

Hope this helps :-)